# Display values in a table using AJAX

Tags: jquery, html, css, ajax, grails

I have a controller in which I am rendering values to a GSP page as:

`reply = [status:false, value1:arrayList2, value2: arrayList3,value3: arrayList4,value4: arrayList1] render status: 200, text:(reply as JSON).toString()`.

Inside the AJAX `success` function I am getting the value `like` and trying to display it as:

```
var retrievedValue = JSON.parse(data);
if(retrievedValue.value1.length > 0){
    alert("first array value")
    var row1 = '<tr>';
    var col1 = '';
    for(var i=0;i<retrievedValue.value1.length;i++)
    col1 += '<td>'+retrievedValue.value1[i]+'</td>';
    row1 += '</tr>';
    $('#table1').append(row);
}
if(retrievedValue.value2.length > 0){
    alert("second array value")
    var row2 = '<tr>';
    var col2 = '';
    for(var i=0;i<retrievedValue.value2.length;i++)
    col2 += '<td>'+retrievedValue.value2[i]+'</td>';
    row2 += '</tr>';
    $('#table1').append(row);
}

if(retrievedValue.value3.length > 0){
    alert("third array value")
    var row3 = '<tr>';
    var col3 = '';
    for(var i=0;i<retrievedValue.value3.length;i++)
    col3 += '<td>'+retrievedValue.value3[i]+'</td>';
    row3 += '</tr>';
    $('#table1').append(row);
}
if(retrievedValue.value4.length > 0){
    alert("fourth array value")
    var row4 = '<tr>';
    var col4 = '';
    for(var i=0;i<retrievedValue.value4.length;i++)
    col4 += '<td>'+retrievedValue.value4[i]+'</td>';
    row4 += '</tr>';
    $('#table1').append(row);
}
```

but it is not displaying anything as a table. This is my table area:

```
<table id ="table1"> </table>
```

How to populate the list of values in the table as separate rows?

Comment: show what your `arrayList2`, `arrayList3` contains..

Comment: Make sure to check [MCVE] guide on posting code. Half of the function is rarely enough to demonstrate the problem.

Comment: @Guruprasad Rao it will be having 0000-00-00-00.00.00.000001

Comment: @raghulc when you did ` alert("Values are: "+data)` did you see actual values ? if so did you need JSON.parse ?? Since i suspect ` var retrievedValue = JSON.parse(data);` is not needed at all.  I think if you tried if(data.value1.length > 0){ it would work. Can you please verify that worked and if so would you not consider maybe slowing down and evaluating/understanding step by step development rather than bigData I am confused in the midst of all the data. start small work your way up. At most this should have been 1 basic iteration obviously it don't work in 1 it won't in 10 why post all

Comment: @vahid if i am not parsing the JSON using  var retrievedValue = JSON.parse(data) then in when i try to get the values it is coming as undefined alert("success: "+data.value1) the success is undefined but it has values in it

Comment: @vahid i am rendering the values from the controller as reply = [status:false, value1:arrayList2, value2: arrayList3,value3: arrayList4,value4: arrayList1] render status: 200, text:(reply as JSON).toString()

Comment: indeed and it is most likely that you do need to parse the JSON but if you read through my answer properly. Development is all about questioning each line that you are about to use rather than copying pasting. When you copy paste you understand less of what it is you are actually doing. But by questioning each line like i have shown you will hardly hit this confusions since you are analysing each line by line and capturing a problem before it becomes a problem

Comment: @vahid yes i am getting your point. but the thing is i am short of time and need to complete this. Anyways thanks for your thoughts

Comment: Did you ever get this sorted,  I had a similar issue today and took a few attempts to work out what was going on. Slightly different the controller returned a map as JSON. So no String. Now in the ajax success i was able to see data like this  `success: function(data){
   data.forEach(function(entry) {
    console.log('JSON '+entry.id+' '+entry.navCode)
   });` So you see no parsing required there... controller states `render values as JSON`

Comment: @vahid in my case i am rendering the value from the controller as [status:false, value1:arrayList2, value2: arrayList3,value3: arrayList4,value4: arrayList1] render status: 200, text:(reply as JSON).toString() so in the gsp page without parsing if i get the value as data.status i am getting undefined,so need to parse first and then only will be able to get the data

Comment: I ony asked if it had worked and outlined a scenario where it wasn't needed. I suspect if you droppped to .toString you may then not need to parse it.

Answer (score 0):

You're appending a variable named row each time but your rows are named row1, row2...
I'm sure you can streamline the whole approach but e.g. for your first block:

```
var row = '<tr>';
var col = '';
for(var i=0;i<retrievedValue.value1.length;i++) {
    col += '<td>'+retrievedValue.value1[i]+'</td>';
}
row += col;
row += '</tr>';
$('#table1').append(row);
```

Comment: i am looking to display the values under two columns like Time1 Time2.. Also what do you mean by 'you can streamline the whole approach'

Answer (score 0):

I think what @Mike W meant was that you can find another way / approach to make your condition worked as a whole.

Your sample code isn't very detailed and some parts are missing (like what is exactly the data structure of your {reply} value)

This code block may guide you on how to populate list of values as separate rows. Use this as a reference

```
// assuming that you are getting the ajax response in an {object format
// that had a list of {array} values
var oAjaxResponse = {
    value1: ['Sample 1', 'Geo 1', '250.00'],
    value2: ['Sample 2', 'Geo 2', '255.00'],
    value3: ['Sample 3', 'Geo 3', '300.00'],
    value4: ['Sample 4', 'Geo 4', '250.00'],
    value5: ['Sample 5', 'Geo 5', '255.00'],
    value6: ['Sample 6', 'Geo 6', '300.00']
};

var oMainTable = $('#tbl-main');
var sHtmlRowsData = '';
for (var iIndex in oAjaxResponse) {
    sHtmlRowsData += '<tr>';

    var aArrayList = oAjaxResponse[iIndex];
    for (var iValueLength = 0; iValueLength < aArrayList.length; iValueLength++) {
        sHtmlRowsData += '<td>' + aArrayList[iValueLength] + '</td>';
    }

    sHtmlRowsData += '</tr>';
}

oMainTable.find('tbody').append(sHtmlRowsData);
```

Here's a jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Lzha2nwp/

Comment: how can i make the value to be populate in the second column, like i need to decide which value should be in second column

Comment: Huh? You wanted to have a condition to decide which value you wanted to show on the second column? Can you provide a scenario of what you want to accomplish with this? Why would you wanted to do that?

Comment: the four arraylist that i am rendering from the controller will have list of values like 0000-00-00-00.00.00.000001. so 1st arraylist value should be in first column it should not be displayed in second and second arraylist value should be in second column it should not be displayed there in the first

Comment: Did you find the solution for your concern now?

Answer (score 0):

I have seen a few questions related to jquery recently from you and if I can be honest. I think if you are that involved in something maybe it is time you picked up a book and read up on the basics of jquery and java scripts. Since the quality of the questions tend to be poor and the typical run around you cause could have all be avoided if you understood the most basic of all things when it comes to java scripting. I will show you as pointed out on comment and this is rather an important aspect of JSON in javascript since everything communicated internal is JSON typically.

```
success: function(data){   
   //unsure why you are using alerts (annoying due to confirmation)
   //use console.log instead and open developer console f12
   alert("Values are: "+data)
   //at this point what this alert ?
   // did it show human readable objects 
   // or did it return [Object:Object]
   //since if you wanted to now delve into what this really was 
   console.log('Values are "+JSON.strinigify(data));
   //this would now show me the content of [Object:Object]


   var retrievedValue = JSON.parse(data);
    //where were these debugs 
   //console.log('JSON parsed '+retrievedValue);
   //console.log('JSON parsed '+JSON.stringify(retrievedValue));
   //where they required since it maybe that  instead of 
   if(retrievedValue.value1.length > 0){
   //should have been:
   if(data.value1.length > 0){
    //and so on
```

But as you can see from above example, you haven't fully debugged each of your steps even before hitting iteration and you write a confused statement as to why it doesn't work.

Try to understand the basics of something before delving deep into it. That will help you easily identify the simpler issues that turn a small problem into as shown a big old problem